# How can I structure a full stack project with Node.js and ReactJS to allow for REST API type sharing and local testing?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, architecture

I have a full stack project with Node.JS backend and ReactJS frontend, both using Typescript.
What would be the best way to structure the project?
I need the ability to share REST API types between frontend and backend and to be able to run locally without the need to run npm publish.

At the moment I have this:

```
<ROOT>
|
|
+--> ui
|       package.json
|       ...
+--> backend
|       package.json
|       ...
```

Thinking about adding a common directory as well, but looking for suggestions best practices.